# How to make a postman request to kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin, postman, kotlin-coroutines

I have following coroutine function and I want to make a postman request the endpoint. Application started on http://localhost:8080

```
    @Configuration
class MerchantApi {

    @Bean
    fun routes(paymentHandler: paymentHandler) = coRouter {
        "/payment-link".nest {
            POST("/init") { serverRequest ->
                //logic here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried as below but it gives a 404 error. 
[image]

I am using gradle and this is the build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:$glassfish_jaxb_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.3.61'
}

group = "payapp"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation "com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:$fuel_version"
    implementation "com.beust:klaxon:$klaxon_version"
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.4.RELEASE")
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hosted is `/payment-link`, postman calls `/create-link`.

Comment: Mistake. I have updated the image

Comment: Are you using spring boot?

Comment: yes. spring boot

Comment: What is the path of the class with @SpringBootApplication and the path of this file `MerchantApi`?

Comment: @SpringBootApplication:
/main/kotlin/payapp/boot  
          
          MerchantApi:
/main/kotlin/payapp/link/api

Comment: @Ruchira that is the problem. Since `MerchantApi` is not in the same path as the class with `SpringBootApplication`, it is not able to scan that file automatically for generating the beans, unless you explicitly specify that. So either move the `MerchantApi` class to be within `/main/kotlin/payapp/boot` or include the `MerchantApi` class in the component scan by   `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ["payapp"])`

Comment: @MadhuBhat scanBasePackages is already added. I have tried by moving MerchantApi to boot directory also. But no luck

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle or pom.xml contents to the question?

Comment: @Ruchira remove the dependency for `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")` from your gradle file. Then it would work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are facing is due to including both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` modules in your dependencies. The below is from the Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-webflux):

> Adding both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux`
>   modules in your application results in Spring Boot auto-configuring
>   **Spring MVC**, not **WebFlux**. This behavior has been chosen because many
>   Spring developers add `spring-boot-starter-webflux` to their Spring MVC
>   application to use the reactive `WebClient`. You can still enforce your
>   choice by setting the chosen application type to
>   `SpringApplication.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.REACTIVE)`.

Since you need the route generated via the webflux module, you would have to either remove the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency from your `build.gradle` file, or else configure the `webApplicationType` of your app as `REACTIVE` as below:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<ClassName>(*args) {
        webApplicationType = WebApplicationType.REACTIVE
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ruchira did this answer your question?